# How can I use brew install to install enthought canopy for ipython? And would the fact that I already have a different version of iPython matter?

Tags: ipython, homebrew, enthought, canopy

And would the fact that I already have a different version of iPython matter? I already used brew install to get ipython, but I need to use Enthought Canopy for a class, so I need to download that also.

Answer (score 0):

1) You can't install canopy with homebrew. If you have an academic email address, request a canopy academic license at https://store.enthought.com/#canopy-academic . Whether you do or not, download from https://store.enthought.com/downloads/ and install following the instructions there.

2) When you first run Canopy, un-check "Make Canopy my default Python" and there should be no conflict with your existing install. See https://support.enthought.com/entries/23646538-Make-Canopy-User-Python-be-your-default-Python